# Can't run function in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I run this function:

```
- (void)insertRows {
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

and it must run this function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
    return cell;
}
```

but this function is not run... please help how run tableView... function

```
- (IBAction)insertObject {
    [[MasterViewController alloc] insertRows];
}
```

- this code run insertRows, i check this by breakpoint

```
- (IBAction)insertObject:(id)sender {
    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0   inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    NSLog(@"log:insert-indexPath: %i",indexPath.row);
    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"log:insert-object %@",object.description);
 }
```

-works with it, why?

Comment: Could `self.tableview` be nil?

Comment: Chuck, no... because if i run insertRow by IBAction(tap button) tableView... works...

Comment: So probably you aren't calling that method.

Comment: Ramy, i am calling this method in (IBAction)insertObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues in this code:

• Probably want to `addObject:` to `_objects`, not `insertObject:atIndex:`.

• `[[MasterViewController alloc] insertRows];` doesn't make sense.   There needs to be an `init` somewhere.

• You should never use the `description` method as a means of displaying something to the user.  `description` is intended for debugging and logging only.

• To trigger the invocation of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you would typically `reload` the table.  I.e. that method is called by the table view when it is updating itself.

I'd suggest starting with the [table view programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

Comment: but why this work with it(see topic)